# ISNUMBER to detect unique due dates to highlight the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

`B49 to I49` has the completed date which is unique for each of my employees
`B50 to I50` is a formula that adds a year to the completed date as that is when it is due. The range of data is `$B$49:$I$62`

What I am trying to acheive is highlighting the cells in `B50 to I50` once it is within 90/60/30/14/today of the date in `B50 to I50.`

Below is the formula I am using but it is not working.

`B50 to I50` is the due date plus one year `=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))`

The formula for `B50 to I50` is as follows and is applied to `$B$50:$I$50,$B$52:$I$52` and so forth.

```
> =AND(ISNUMBER(B50:I50),B50:I50<=TODAY())
> =AND(ISNUMBER(B50:I50),B50:I50<=TODAY()+14)
> =AND(ISNUMBER(B50:I50),B50:I50<=TODAY()+30)
> =AND(ISNUMBER(B50:I50),B50:I50<=TODAY()+60)
> =AND(ISNUMBER(B50:I50),B50:I50<=TODAY()+90)

+---------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|                           | Employee 1  | Employee 2  | Employee 3  |
+---------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Training #1 Complete Date | 17-May-2018 | 07-Jul-2018 | 16-Sep-2017 |
| Training #1 Due Date      | 17-May-2019 | 07-Jul-2019 | 16-Sep-2018 |
| Training #2 Complete Date | 19-Jul-2018 | 19-Jul-2018 | 19-Jul-2018 |
| Training #2 Due Date      | 19-Jul-2019 | 19-Jul-2019 | 19-Jul-2019 |
+---------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

This does not properly highlight the cells at all.

Comment: Are you using one single rule for defining your conditional formatting? In case yes, I'd advise you to split this over different rules.

Comment: I have 5 different rules that is applied for the entire range.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use one cell reference to create the rule then apply that formatting to all the required cells

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(B50),B50 <= TODAY()+14)
```

You can create all your rules like that and apply them to the range, the priority of the rules is also very important. The sequence you have mentioned in your question seems correct.